# Display Transfers Button at the far right corner

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

```
<div class="account-tile" qa-name="accountBlock">
  <a
    *ngIf="link"
    class="account-detail-header"
    [routerLink]="'/AccountDetails/' + account.index!"
  >
    <div qa-name="accountName" class="account-name">
      {{ account.accountName }}
    </div>
    <div qa-name="accountNumber" class="account-number">
      ...{{ account.number | lastFour }}
    </div>
    <span>
      <i class="gg-chevron-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <div *ngIf="!link" class="account-detail-header">
    <div qa-name="accountName" class="account-name">
      {{ account.accountName }}
    </div>
    <div qa-name="accountNumber" class="account-number">
      ...{{ account.number | lastFour }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="available-balance-container">
    <div class="flex">
      <span class="negative-account" *ngIf="account.availableBalance! < 0"
        >-</span
      >
      <span
        [ngClass]="link ? 'format-dollar-link' : 'format-dollar-display'"
        class="format-dollar"
      >
        $
      </span>
      <h2 qa-name="availableBalance">
        {{ account.availableBalance | currency: '':'' | absolute }}
      </h2>
<!--This is wheere the transfer button appears-->
<div class="parent=class">
<button class="button-right pull-right">Transfer</button>
</div>
    </div>
    <h3>Available Balance</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I am trying to display a transfer button at the right corner to look like the picture above. How can I accomplish that? I tried creating a button and a class that pulls the button to the right. when I compile the code, the transfer button shows underneath the Account amount

Comment: I don't see any transfer button in your code

Comment: Where's the transfer button? Can you share a link with a reproducible example?

Comment: I have updated the HTML so it displays the transfer button

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position: absolute` to your transfer button.

```css
.parent-class {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-class">
  <button class="button-right">Transfer</button>
</div>
```